# Python dataframe algorithm parent category

Tags: python, pandas

just need help to deploy recursive category algorhitm.

I have this dataframe

```
ID, PRICE, CAT_NAME, PARENT_CAT_NAME,TITLE
1, 25€, RED_WINE, WINES, Red wine from ....
2, 15€, BLACK_WINE,WINES, Nice black wine
3, 10€,WINES,DRINKS, Generic white wine...
4, 10, WOMEN_TSHIRT, WOMEN, Summer women T-Shirt
5, 10, WOMEN, DRESSES, Women winter dress
```

ok now i would like to generate a dynamic algorithm to recreate dataframe with full path CATEGORIES in diferent columns

For example final data set looks like this.

```
ID,PRICE,CAT_1,CAT_2,CAT_3 ... CAT_X, TITLE
1, 25€, DRINKS,WINES,RED_WINE,...NULL Red wine from..
2, 14€, DRINKS,WINES,BLACK_WINES,...NULL, Nice black wine...
3, 10€, DRINKS,WINES, NULL,...NULL Generic white wine...
```

etc...

Note on all data set i can have X inherithed categories 
this is some items have 3 categories and some item could have 5 or more sub categories.. for example if maxim inherited parent category is 10 then we need 10 new CAT_X columns on dataframe and set null.
On Wine example could look like this

```
DRINKS,WINES;RED_WIN,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL...
```

Im not a python expert and i apreciate you help or some coding idea. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please re-frame this with an expected output that's consistent with your example input?

Comment: Thanks roganjosh i mistaked i edited on initial post final data set look like second code section